# Android, use same onActivityResult for Images, Video and Audio

Tags: android, image, audio, video, media

I want to use the same onActivityResult for Images, Video and Audio.

The problem.
When i pick audio, it saves the path for audio in both video and images.
I am having problems separating images, video and audio.

My code.

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 1;
```

Audio, images, video

```
addVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        }
    });

    addAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio"),SELECT_AUDIO);
        }
    });

    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
            Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
            selectedVideoPath = getPath(selectedVideoUri);
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO) {
            Uri selectedAudioUri = data.getData();
            selectedAudioPath = getPath(selectedAudioUri);
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            File f = new File(selectedImagePath);
            if(f.exists()){
                //w, h
                Bitmap myBitmap = resizeImage.getCompressedBitmap(200, 200, f);
                img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the same id for all your request codes

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 1;
```

OnActivityResult can't tell the difference then. You should give them an unique id.

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Charm Geldjust update your static value according this..

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 3;
```